# Print out first letter of third word in string

Tags: java

The task is this: print out the first letter of the third word of SongLine. 
The tutor/demonstrator says I should use a loop.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SongApp{

public static void main(String[] args){

Song song1 = new Song("While my guitar weeps");
Song song2 = new Song("Let it be");
//Song song3 = new Song("Penny Lane");

String str1 = song1.toString();
String str2 = song2.toString();

System.out.println(song1.toString());
//System.out.println("Length is: " + str1.length());
System.out.println(song2.toString());
//System.out.println("Length is: " + str2.length());

//System.out.println(str1.charAt(str1.length()-1));
//System.out.println(str2.charAt(str2.length()-1));

int s1 = str1.indexOf(' ');
System.out.println(str1.substring(0, str1.indexOf(' ', s1 +1)));
//System.out.println(str1.substring(str1.indexOf(' ', s1 + 2)));

int s2 = str2.indexOf(' ');
System.out.println(str2.substring(0, str2.indexOf(' ', s2 +1)));
//System.out.println(str2.substring(str2.indexOf(' ', s2 + 1)));
 } 
}

public class Song{

  private String songLine;

  public Song (String sLine){
    songLine = sLine;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return songLine;
  }

  public void process(){}

}
```

I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed.

I also need to print the first two words which I've done, but need to print the rest of the string on another line, so far I have it mostly working apart for the extra space at the beginning.

Thanks,
JXDee

Comment: please post expected output as per above input

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

Song song1 = new Song("While my guitar weeps");
Song song2 = new Song("Let it be");

String str1 = song1.toString();
String str2 = song2.toString();

 int x=0;
 int currentSpace=0;
 String wordResult="";
 while (x<song1.length()){

   if (song1.charAt(x)=' ') {
     currentSpace++;
    }
   if (currentSpace = 2) {
   wordResult =wordResult + song1.charAt(x);
  }
 x++;
 }
 System.out.println("The first character is: " + wordResult.charAt(0));
 System.out.println("The result is :" + wordResult);

} 
}
```

Ive edited the code so that it will fit to your need which is using the while loop. As you can see, the loop will check all the characters. The loop will also look for the spaces.. when the loop scan that the space reaches 2 the it will start to record the 3rd word in the sentence. character by character. as you can see there is a condition that if the currentSpace variable is still 2 then it will keep recording the characters until it reaches the next space or the end of sentence.. then lastly on printing to get the first character of 3rd word we will just use the charAt to finished it.. i hope this helps

Comment: I appreciate the fast response, but the demonstrator wants it in a loop. We're also not up to arrays yet.

Comment: Wait, so as a condition no using of arrays?

Comment: Do far we have been doing 'if, else, while, do, case' loops, but no arrays and the demonstrator didn't specify which loop to use.

Comment: @JXDee: You can check my answer, which has `While` loop and no usage of `array`. I understand demonstrators want different answer.

Comment: I just edited the code using the while loop.. i hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

A working solution: :-)

```
String x = "While my guitar weeps";
x= x.trim();

for(int i=1; i<=2; i++)
  x = x.substring(x.indexOf(" ")+1) ;

char reqChar = x.charAt(0);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: Hi @JoeC, thanks for the point. I didn't explained intentionally. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
    String word = "One Two Three";
    int space = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    while(space<2){
        if(word.charAt(ch)==' '){               
            space++;
        }
        ch++;           
    }
    System.out.println(word.charAt(ch));
```

This works. You know its the beginning of the third word when space=1. So the next character will be the character you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Comment: @JoeC I understand. But i guess that's all the explanation the code needs